# Munging non-printable characters to dots using string.translate()

Tags: python, code-golf

So I've done this before and it's a surprising ugly bit of code for such a seemingly simple task.

The goal is to translate any non-printable character into a **.** (dot).  For my purposes "printable" does exclude the last few characters from `string.printable` (new-lines, tabs, and so on).  This is for printing things like the old MS-DOS debug "hex dump" format ... or anything similar to that (where additional whitespace will mangle the intended dump layout).

I know I can use `string.translate()` and, to use that, I need a translation table.  So I use `string.maketrans()` for that. Here's the best I could come up with:

```
filter = string.maketrans(
   string.translate(string.maketrans('',''),
   string.maketrans('',''),string.printable[:-5]),
   '.'*len(string.translate(string.maketrans('',''),
   string.maketrans('',''),string.printable[:-5])))
```

... which is an unreadable mess (though it does work).

From there you can call use something like:

```
for each_line in sometext:
    print string.translate(each_line, filter)
```

... and be happy.  (So long as you don't look under the hood).

Now it is more readable if I break that horrid expression into separate statements:

```
ascii = string.maketrans('','')   # The whole ASCII character set
nonprintable = string.translate(ascii, ascii, string.printable[:-5])  # Optional delchars argument
filter = string.maketrans(nonprintable, '.' * len(nonprintable))
```

And it's tempting to do that just for legibility.

However, I keep thinking there has to be a more elegant way to express this!

Comment: You can just use `each_line.translate(filter)` in your loop

Comment: I didn't think of an "elegant" tag. :(  (And I don't see how to add tags after the fact).

Comment: If code golfing the whole process (replacing all non-printable characters) is your goal, then you can the one liner (assuming `my_str` is the string you want to translate) `''.join(list(map(lambda x: ['.',x][x in set(string.printable[:-5])], my_str))`

However, I'd probably prefer to use: `''.join(list(map(lambda x: x if (x in set(string.printable[:-5])) else '.', my_str)))` for the marginal improvement in clarity

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's another approach using a list comprehension:

```
filter = ''.join([['.', chr(x)][chr(x) in string.printable[:-5]] for x in xrange(256)])
```

Comment: Oh, that's evil!  Relying on the 0/1 numeric value of the condition as an index off a two item list containing '.' and each character in turn. I like it!

Comment: @JimDennis: Explaining the solution while complimenting it. I like that more!

Answer (score 4):

Broadest use of "ascii" here, but you get the idea

```
>>> import string
>>> ascii="".join(map(chr,range(256)))
>>> filter="".join(('.',x)[x in string.printable[:-5]] for x in ascii)
>>> ascii.translate(filter)
'................................ !"#$%&\'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~.................................................................................................................................'
```

If I were golfing, probably use something like this:

```
filter='.'*32+"".join(map(chr,range(32,127)))+'.'*129
```

Answer (score 1):

for actual code-golf, I imagine you'd avoid string.maketrans entirely

```
s=set(string.printable[:-5])
newstring = ''.join(x for x in oldstring if x in s else '.')
```

or

```
newstring=re.sub('[^'+string.printable[:-5]+']','',oldstring)
```

Comment: regex is a nice answer for golfing, but would be *much* slower than translate.

Comment: this question shouldn't be tagged [code-golf] if it wasn't meant to be golfed ;) but I did have a sneaking suspicion OP actually wanted an answer using maketrans.

Comment: yes it should probably should be tagged *elegant* instead of *code-colf* ;)

Comment: I love the .join with a conditional expression, though I can't use it for now (too much of my target base is still running Python 2.4.x).

Answer (score 1):

I don't find this solution ugly. It is certainly more efficient than any regex based solution. Here is a tiny bit shorter solution. But only works in python2.6:

```
nonprintable = string.maketrans('','').translate(None, string.printable[:-5])
filter = string.maketrans(nonprintable, '.' * len(nonprintable))
```